# My Query is not giving the right results in access

Tags: sql, date, ms-access, ms-access-2016

```
SELECT (SignIn.VisitorFirstName & " " & SignIn.VisitorLastName) AS [Visitor Name], SignIn.SignInDateTime AS [Sign In Time], ([UserList.FirstName] & " " & [UserList.LastName]) AS Reason
FROM SignIn INNER JOIN UserList ON SignIn.AssignedPO = UserList.POid
WHERE (((SignIn.Complete)=No) AND ((Format([SignInDateTime],"Short Date")) Between #8/8/2016# And #8/10/2016#))
ORDER BY SignIn.SignInDateTime;
```

I am getting values for dates outside the scope.

The query runs but returns the wrong values. (see image below)
**

> **EDIT from comments: It's returning values before August 8th**

**

[image]

Properties of my DateTime field (SignInDateTime)

[image]

Comment: Ok. So you state that you get values that are outside the scope, but without seeing any data for the SignInDateTime column how do you think anyone could say what might be the problem? Also, what does the data look like, and what did you expect from the query? _More information needed_

Comment: My result is getting data from before 8/8

Comment: Please tell me why you're down voting. I am not asking you to do the work for me but to explain why my query is not giving any errors and why it's showing values before 8/8/2016. It isnt showing values after 8/10/2016

Comment: @softwareisfun While I wasn't the one who down voted I would guess it might have been as the question was unclear. Without source and expected data a question of the type _i did this, and something is wrong_ is pretty hard to answer. To give a good answer three parts are needed: data before, query and expected output. Your question lacked two of the three items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what this conversion/comparison is doing

```
((Format([SignInDateTime],"Short Date"))
```

You might be safe to use `CDate` or just the Field itself - it looks like it's a date time field anyways

**If it is a Date/Time field, try changing this**

```
((Format([SignInDateTime],"Short Date"))
```

**To this**

```
([SignInDateTime]
```

Comment: That showed me dates on 8/8 but nothing on 8/10. I thought And was inclusive of the start and end. It seems to be getting 8/8 and 8/9

Comment: Your BETWEEN command ends 8/10 - if you want to include all times on 8/10 add the time 23:59:59 to your end date - ie. `#8/10/2016 23:59:59#`

Comment: SELECT SignIn.VisitorFirstName As [First Name], SignIn.VisitorLastName As [Last Name], SignIn.SignInDateTime As [Sign In Time] FROM SignIn WHERE (((SignIn.Complete)=No) AND ((SignIn.[SignInDateTime]) Between #8/11/2016# And #8/12/2016 23:59:59#)) ORDER BY SignIn.SignInDateTime;

Comment: I added rows to have dates between 8/10 to 8/12. I am getting 0 rows returned

Comment: Nice moving target - did it work with your August 10th data? I doubt it's broken now by adding data - update your question with your actual data and your new actual query. It's like we're trying to fix everything twice - you probably added rows with default `"Complete=Yes"`